# jQuery animate height, why does my div animate in from the left?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

Morning!

So I have a notification div which when activated will either have a success or error class added to it which just add different background colors.

For some reason when the notification div animates fades it, the color from the added success or error class animates in from the top left, instead of just straight down.

[image]

My jsFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/leongaban/DPUVg/

HTML

```
<div class="notification-container"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.notification-container {
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 56px;
    background: #ccc;
}

.alert-success, .alert-error {
    width: 100%;
    height: 56px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 56px;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.alert-success { width: 100%; background: blue; }
.alert-error { width: 100%; background: red; }
```

jQuery

```
var jsonFakeBoolean = true;

if (jsonFakeBoolean) {
    $container = $('<div id="notification-div">');
    $container.html($('<h4>').html('This is an Alert MSG!'));
    $container.addClass('alert-success');
    $container.hide();
    $container.appendTo('.notification-container');
    $container.show('slow');

    $('.notification-container').fadeIn('slow');
    $('.notification-container').animate({
    opacity: 1,
    height:'+=56px' },
    500, function() {
    /* stuff to do after fading in is done */
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.notification-container').fadeOut('slow', function () {
                $('.notification-container').empty();
                alert('done');
            });
        }, 15000);
    });

    return $container;
}
```

Resulting HTML from Chrome console
[image]

Any thoughts? Things that stick out here :(

Comment: This is the natural behavior of show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [.slideDown](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) instead of .show()

[<kbd>jsFiddle Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/DPUVg/20/)

```
$container.slideDown('slow');
```

Comment: Ah thanks! Forgot about slideDown... btw how do you create that jsFiddle Demo button?

Answer (score 2):

Try changing

```
$container.show('slow');
```

with

```
$container.slideDown('slow');
```

On line 8 of your JS code.